# How to extend django user default models database

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, database

I am currently creating an online e-commerce website in Django, however, I am using the following library that already has a readily available user table.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username','first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password','phone','address']
```

my products and basket are made in models.py and they work fine,

however, the problem I am having is for the user field I need to have at least: name, email, phone and address. but when i view the table created it only has, username, first_name, last_name and password, it doesn't implement phone and address into the table created!

[image of tables through admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuFfq.png)

does anyone know how i am able to do this?

Comment: what version of django are you using?

Comment: @JamesR I'm using version '1.10.5'

Comment: `ModelForm` creates a Form from a Model, which in your case is `User`. User model doesn't have `phone` or `address`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to extend **User** model try the following:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```